# Angularjs: Form validation & debounce / blur

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-directive

I create a form based on the AngularJS's documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms). The JSFiddle of my issue is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7197/

Making a basic "user registration form" raises a question about validation. I want the validation to run as the "email" input field has lost focus. I understand the following directive needs to be specified:

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
```

However, the validation occurs in real time as text is input. Can you please have a look, I can't find what I'm doing wrong...

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
```

That future is available in angularjs version 1.3

please see working example here http://jsfiddle.net/ftcpsfxv/

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0-beta.13/angular.js
```